# Pull up and external interrupt output on GPIO of a raspberry pi 4

Tags: gpio, pi-4

Currently I am working on programming some pins of the GPIO interface on a Raspberry pi 4 without using any high-level library (like wiringPi etc...). I just found this link that was helpful (https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples#Direct_register_access). I am facing some problems when it comes to program a pin as an external interrupt or as a GPIO pull up. I didn't know what should I do or how to program it. May someone help me ?
Also I didn't fully understand these 3 lines of GPIO macros

```
#define INP_GPIO(g) *(gpio+((g)/10)) &= ~(7<<(((g)%10)*3))
#define OUT_GPIO(g) *(gpio+((g)/10)) |=  (1<<(((g)%10)*3))
#define SET_GPIO_ALT(g,a) *(gpio+(((g)/10))) |= (((a)<=3?(a)+4:(a)==4?3:2)<<(((g)%10)*3))
```

Comment: I suggest you look at one of the C GPIO libraries.  Study how they set up interrupts and pulls.  Study how they implement the macros.

Comment: Can you please suggest for me a functional library ?

Comment: elinux has a list. Take your pick.